# sending vector objetcs in blender over network

Tags: python, sockets, networking, blender

How to send a vector object.
I am trying to send an object's location in vector format over a udp socket connection.

```
socket.sendto(self.cube.worldPosition,server_addr)
```

but i get the following error:
TypeError: 'Vector' does not support the buffer interface

How can i achieve this or is there any other way to send the position of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply access the values of vector,form a list and send using pickle module

```
    ##player.worldPosition is the vector        
    x = player.worldPosition[0]
    y = player.worldPosition[1]
    z = player.worldPosition[2]                      
    xyz = [x,y,z] #forming the list
    ddd = pickle.dumps(xyz) #serialize the list
    self.socket.sendto(ddd,self.server_address) #off it goes
```

this worked for me

Comment: Don't use the pickle module.  See the red box on this page?  <http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html>.  Heed it.  I suggest AMP instead: <http://amp-protocol.net/>